# Delete TMP file in a local folder

Tags: c#, uwp

I have these files in my local folder.

[image]

As you can see from the image above, there is a TMP file in it. I don't know how it is generated but I believe it is a useless temp file, so I try to delete it this way:

```
        foreach (var item in await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFilesAsync())
            if (item.Name.EndsWith(".TMP"))
                await item.DeleteAsync();
```

However, using neither `GetFilesAsync()` nor `GetItemsAsync()` finds the temp file. The former gives me the json files only and the latter finds everything but the tmp file.

How should I find and delete it?

Comment: Looks like its being edited, and thats a hidden/system file from say word..

Comment: @BugFinder I don't think so because I can delete it manually without Windows telling me it is being edited.

Comment: The TMP may be generated with NewtonJson package, I tried create temp and delete it with above code successful. Please check if file's property is hidden type.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT If it is hidden type, how should I delete this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code to detect the hidden file where in the sandbox(It only works in sandbox).

```
public static class ParseDir
{
    public static FileInfo[] GetFilesFromDirectory(string DirName, string pattern, bool Recursive)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(DirName))
            throw new Exception("No such Directory.");
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(DirName);
        SearchOption Recur = Recursive ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
        return dirInfo.GetFiles(pattern, Recur);
    }

    public static FileInfo[] GetHiddenOnlyFiles(FileInfo[] Files)
    {
        List<FileInfo> result = new List<FileInfo>();
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            if ((file.Attributes & System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) == System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden)
                result.Add(file);
        return result.ToArray();
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
 FileInfo[] filesInS = ParseDir.GetFilesFromDirectory(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "*.*", false);
 FileInfo[] hiddenFiles = ParseDir.GetHiddenOnlyFiles(filesInS);
 hiddenFiles.First().Delete();
```